# VsCode "editor.occurrencesHighlight" set to "multiFile" not working as expected

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to configure my vscode to highlight the selected word in all the current opened documents. As stated in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings :

```
 // Controls whether occurrences should be highlighted across open files.
  //  - off: Does not highlight occurrences.
  //  - singleFile: Highlights occurrences only in the current file.
  //  - multiFile: Experimental: Highlights occurrences across all valid open files.
  "editor.occurrencesHighlight": "singleFile",
```

As you can see in my config file, I set that config value to multifile, but even restarting the app, and setting both files to the same kind of file (I tried different values, but lts say, for example, a shell file), The selection highligh only work in the same file.

Is there any other thing I should be aware of?

Here are some pics:

[image: vscode config file]

and this other one:
[image]

Thanks to all in advance!

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry. I cannot explain why, but it suddently started working as expected.

Thanks anyway!